# Как рассчитать смещение отрезков на заданном большем отрезке, чтобы их наложение было всегда одинаковым по отношению к друг другу?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

довольно сложно сформулировать словами, но я постараюсь описать то, что я хочу.

Есть временное окно (T_period), есть минимальное время работы элемента (T_element_min).
Пусть T_period = T_element_min * N_elements (кол-во элементов)
T_element_max = T_period

На первой шаге элементы включаются друг за другом на минимальное время. Соответсвтенно, элементы работают друг за другом, без перекрытия.

На последующих итерациях время работы элементов увеличивается, соответственно появляются перекрытия.

Как рассчитать время включения элементов на каждом шаге, чтобы перекрытия были одинаковыми между собой?

Последняя итерация - все элементы работают полное время периода.

Пожалуйста, посмотрите приложенный рисунок. Возможно, так будет понятнее, что я имею в виду.

Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите - пусть длина одного отрезка *t*, смещение отрезка относительно другого - *d*, отрезков *n*.

Тогда второй смещен на *d* (время запуска - *d*), третий - на 2*d*, последний - на (*n*-1)*d*. Так что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, или в ваших обозначениях,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все. Cами решите? :)

Comment: действительно, так просто... Спасибо!

Comment: Тогда принимайте ответ - здесь "спасибо" - птичка слева от ответа :)